# How to paste data a certain number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 lines:

```
L39 = DR
L40 = CR
```

And I want to copy those two lines down a certain number of times which will change each time I do the macro. I have already calculated the number using variable `Template_row`

So if `Template_row` = 128, I would want those 128 rows to be filled down with DR & CR. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlA0P.png)

I'm not sure what other information is needed to assist. It has been suggested to use Autofill, but how do I make the destination the variable number of rows to go down?

I've seen other code use the count function, but as I have previously already used the count function in my code and made it the variable `Template_row, would it be easier/possible to use the variable?

Comment: Edit the Answer and explain a little more about how you want that Data. From what could be understood till now, you can benefit from using `AutoFill`

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to VBA. How would I use `AutoFill` so that it only filled a number of rows and not all the way down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the number of rows to a `range.autofill` Object.

Now if you have number of rows as a variable then this little code

```
Sub Macro15()

Template_row = 128

   With ActiveSheet

        .Range("L39:L40").AutoFill .Range("L39:L" & Template_row + 39)

   End With

End Sub
```

will set `range("L39:L167")` as `DR` & CR

[image]

Now you can play with it and amend it as per your needs.

---

Assuming Active cell is 1st cell in the two cells:

```
 rw = ActiveCell.Row

.Range("L" & rw & ":L" & rw + 1).AutoFill .Range("L" & rw & ":L" & Template_row + rw)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
I need it alternate DR and CR for each row. Is there a way I can do that with the formula?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Another question - if I want to adjust this code for 2 selected cells in the same column L, but the row will be different each time, how would I do that?
I've tried using `Activecell` but I don't think I've written it correctly.

`With Sheets("Template")
                .Range(ActiveCell).AutoFill .Range(ActiveCell & ":L" & month_row + 39)
        End With`

Comment: It is already taking 2 Cells `.Range("L39:L40").AutoFill` , 39 & 40

Comment: Yes - but I am meaning that I wouldn't know the row as it would be different everytime. It would still be column L but it may be L60 and 61 or L85 and 86. How do I adjust the code so it will pick up the active cell - is there a way?

Comment: Added in the Answer

Comment: Super! Thank you!!